# How to use arrows to separate rows or columns of a table

Tags: tables, arrows

How can I use an arrow as a substitute for \hline to create the appearance of an $x$ axis in a table? How would one add an axis name to this line?  How do I create a  similar feature for the vertical separator line?  What can I use instead of say c|c  to make a vertical axis and add a name as in $t$ at the end of arrow?

EDIT

Here is an MWE of a basic table,  I want the horizontal separator to be replaced by an arrow, with a $t$, to represent the $t$-axis. And the vertical separator to be replaced with an arrow pointing downward, showing $x$ to represent the $x$ axis. Due to large size of my table there is no room for additional lines to box the table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c | c c c c c c}
\diagbox{$i$}{$j$} & $0$ & $1$ & $2$ & $3$  &  $4$  &  $5$  \\
\hline
-2& .& .&. &. & . & . \\
-1& .& .&. &. & . & . \\
 0& .& .&. &. & . & . \\
 1& .& .&. &. & . & . \\
 2& .& .&. &. & . & . \\
 3& .& .&. &. & . & . \\
 \end{tabular}
 \end{center}
 \end{table}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: What's your final aim? To create an axis system with a table in it? There may be simpler ways...

Comment: @TeXnician I have two lines; one at the top and one at the left that separate time and space values from the numbers in the body of table. I just want to emphasize on table that time is horizontal and space is vertical pointing down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a simple solution using a TikZ matrix (not fully optimal):

[image: matrix]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (f) [matrix of nodes,row sep=-\pgflinewidth,column 1/.style={nodes={rectangle,draw,minimum width=3em}},column 2/.style={nodes={rectangle,draw,minimum width=3em}}]
{
0   & 6 \\
1   & 3 \\
1   & 3 \\
};
\draw[->] (f.north west) -- (f.north east) node[midway,above] {Time};
\draw[->] (f.north west) -- (f.south west) node[midway,left] {Space};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

A solution with an ordinary array and `pst-node` (+ `auto-pst-pdf` to compile with `pdflatex -shell-escape`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pst-node, auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\[ \begin{pspicture}
    \begin{array}{|c|c|}
      \hline
      \pnode[-1em, 3ex]{O}0 & 6 \pnode[1em, 3ex]{X} \\
      \hline
      1 & 3 \\
      \hline
      \pnode[-1em, -2ex]{Y}1 & 3 \\
      \hline
    \end{array}\everypsbox{\footnotesize}
    \psset{linewidth=0.5pt, linejoin=1, arrows= <->, arrowinset=0.12, labelsep=2pt}
    \psline(X)(O)(Y)\uput[r](X){$t$}
    \psset{linestyle=none, arrows =-, shortput=nab}
    \ncline{O}{X}^{Time}
    \ncline{O}{Y}_[nrot=:U]{Space}
  \end{pspicture}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I get Package ifplatform Warning: 
    shell escape is disabled, so I can only detect \ifwindows.

)

! Package auto-pst-pdf Error: 
    "shell escape" (or "write18") is not enabled:
    auto-pst-pdf will not work!
.

See the auto-pst-pdf package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.134         Or turn off auto-pst-pdf.}
                                        %
?

Comment: Yes, you ghave to add this switch to compile with `pdflatex`. Other solution: remove `aut-pst-pdf` and compile with `xelatex`.